# WinHttpException in Xamarin.UITest

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

When I call `StartApp` in `Xamarin.UITest`, I get a crash from a `WinHttpException`. It says it received an unexpected response from the server. The last line in the log is a call to `POST` http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx/ping. If I post to that endpoint in postman, I get a valid response with the text `pong`. I don't understand why it's failing. This happens on Android emulator and on a real device. Both are Android 7.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code in your emulator http://127.0.0.1:xxxxx referes back to the emulator not your local computer where you have the API.

Install Chrome in your emulator.

In your local computer open Chrome -> Press F12 -> Options -> More Tools and Remote Devices.

[image]

Here you can see you emulator.

Check `Port Forwarding` and add a new rule, like this:

[image]

> Or just use 'ngrok' to access the API (ngrok lets you expose a web
>   server running on the local machine to the internet).
>
> https://ngrok.com/docs#expose

Comment: Xamarin.UITest is actually running an API on the phone, so it's intentional that it calls the API on the emulator (afaik). In this case the tests are running on my PC, and the API on the emulator. The emulator API is being called from the PC to automate the tests. I.e., the API is part of the test tools, not something I'm calling from the app under test. I appreciate the information though.